# Creating const_iterator from raw pointer yields compilation error on macOS

Tags: c++, c++11, macos-sierra, libc++

I have code which used to work when it was compiled with `libstdc++` library on macOS (Sierra 10.12.4). I'm now switching over to `libc++` and it gives compile-time error:

```
main.cpp:41:44: error: calling a private constructor of class 'std::__1::__wrap_iter<const unsigned char *>'
        std::vector<uint8_t>::const_iterator i1 = std::vector<uint8_t>::const_iterator(data);
                                                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iterator:1239:31: note: declared private here
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY __wrap_iter(iterator_type __x) _NOEXCEPT : __i(__x) {}
                              ^
main.cpp:42:44: error: calling a private constructor of class 'std::__1::__wrap_iter<const unsigned char *>'
        std::vector<uint8_t>::const_iterator i2 = std::vector<uint8_t>::const_iterator(data+n);
                                                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iterator:1239:31: note: declared private here
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY __wrap_iter(iterator_type __x) _NOEXCEPT : __i(__x) {}
                              ^
2 errors generated.
```

Apparently, `const_iterator` constructor which takes raw data pointers is now private in macOS' `libc++` library.

The code below fails when compiled as `g++ main.cpp -std=c++11` and succeeds when compiled as `g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

 class Blob {
        public:
            size_t size() const { return (end_-begin_); }
            uint8_t operator[](size_t pos) const { return *(begin_+pos); }
            const uint8_t* data() const { return &(*begin_); }

            Blob(const Blob& b):begin_(b.begin_), end_(b.end_){}
            Blob(const std::vector<uint8_t>::const_iterator& begin, 
                const std::vector<uint8_t>::const_iterator& end):
                begin_(begin), end_(end){}
            Blob& operator=(const Blob& b)
            {
                if (this != &b)
                {
                    begin_ = b.begin_;
                    end_ = b.end_;
                }

                return *this;
            }

            std::vector<uint8_t>::const_iterator begin() const 
            { return begin_; }
            std::vector<uint8_t>::const_iterator end() const
            { return end_; }
        protected:
            std::vector<uint8_t>::const_iterator begin_, end_;

            Blob() = delete;
        };


int main()
{
    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
    int n = 100;
    uint8_t *data = new uint8_t(n);

    Blob b(std::vector<uint8_t>::const_iterator(data), 
        std::vector<uint8_t>::const_iterator(data+n));
}
```

How do I make it compile with `libc++`?

Comment: The C++ standard does not define a constructor for a vector's iterator (`const` or not) that takes a raw, native pointer as a parameter. The fact that this works with one particular C++ library doesn't mean that it'll work with another one.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks. at first I though of wrapping data into a const vector (with custom allocator), but I don't think it's the correct way, since destructor will try to deallocate this memory. I'll better redesign my code, and most likely will have to make a copy of data (which i didn't want to do at first).

Answer (score 0):

Your `Blob` appears to be a crude `gsl::span<const std::uint8_t>`.

Replace it with a `span`.  Write it yourself if you have to.  How y9u use your `Blob` code violates the C++ standard.

Failing that, reimplement Blob in terms of span.  Leave the ctor taking vector iterators if you must, but store pointers in the span.

Failing that,

```
        Blob(const std::vector<uint8_t>::const_iterator& begin, 
            const std::vector<uint8_t>::const_iterator& end
        ):
          Blob(&*begin, &*end)
        {}
        Blob(std::uint8_t const*begin,std::uint8_t const*end):
          begin_(begin), end_(end)
        {}

        uint8_t const* begin() const 
        { return begin_; }
        uint8_t const* end() const
        { return end_; }

        std::uint8_t const* begin_;
        std::uint8_t const* end_;
```